# Run react app with mui - Compiled with problems:

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to run a react app but following errors come.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@mui/styled-engine/GlobalStyles/GlobalStyles.js 3:0-40
ERROR in ./node_modules/@mui/styled-engine/StyledEngineProvider/StyledEngineProvider.js 3:0-47
ERROR in ./node_modules/@mui/styled-engine/index.js 6:0-39
ERROR in ./node_modules/@mui/styled-engine/index.js 30:0-62
ERROR in ./node_modules/@mui/system/esm/ThemeProvider/ThemeProvider.js 11:27-60
ERROR in ./node_modules/@mui/system/esm/index.js 1:0-88
```

I already tried,

```
npm i @mui/styled-engine
npm i @mui/system
```

These are the dependencies in `package.json` file

```
"@mui/icons-material": "^5.5.1",
"@mui/material": "^5.5.2",
"@mui/styled-engine": "^5.5.2",
"@mui/system": "^5.5.2",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
"@testing-library/react": "^12.1.4",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-icons": "^4.3.1",
"react-scripts": "5.0.0",
"styled-components": "^5.3.3",
"web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
```

Comment: can you include the error message? the error you're giving is only indicate where the error occurs and does not give any details into what type of error that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install these two:

- @emotion/react
- @emotion/styled

  npm i @emotion/react @emotion/styled

Comment: Thank you! This solved my error.

Comment: No worries, and also please choose the answer as accepted.